# Stop directory_iterator before moving out of bounds

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to iterate over a directory and read the images inside while allowing to skip every n'th file.

My code currently looks like this:

```
// Count number of files in directory and reserve memory (take skipped slices into account)
std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator it_begin{path};
int count = count_if(it_begin, std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(), [](const std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry & d) {return !is_directory(d.path());});
auto maxCount = count - (count % (1 + skipSlices));
m_imageStack.reserve(maxCount);

// Read image stack and check for validity
int n = 0;
for (std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_iterator it(path); it != std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_iterator(); std::advance(it, 1 + skipSlices))
{
    std::string filename{std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path(*it).string()};
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filename);
    m_imageStack.push_back(image);

    n = n + 1 + skipSlices;
    if (n == maxCount) break;
}
```

If `skipSlices = 1`, I only want to read every 2nd image, etc. For not moving out of bounds, I added a break condition inside the for-loop. My solution right now is a really bad and I would like to get rid of the break and instead use a more correct stop-condition in the for-loop. However, I couldn't find a way to tell the iterator to stop before advancing too much. Any ideas how this could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Just write a version of `advance` that takes a limit.

```
namespace detail {
    template<class It, class Dist>
    void advance_with_limit_impl(It& it, It end, Dist n, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
        if(n > 0) it += std::min(end - it, n);
        else it += std::max(end - it, n);
    }

    template<class It, class Dist>
    void advance_with_limit_impl(It& it, It end, Dist n, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag) {
        if(n > 0) { while(n != 0 && it != end) { --n; ++it; } }
        else { while (n != 0 && it != end) { ++n; --it; } }
    }

    template<class It, class Dist>
    void advance_with_limit_impl(It& it, It end, Dist n, std::input_iterator_tag) {
        while(n != 0 && it != end) { --n; ++it; }
    }
}

template<class It>
void advance_with_limit(It& it, It end, 
                        typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type n) {
    detail::advance_with_limit_impl(it, end, n, 
                               typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category());
}
```

Then just use `advance_with_limit(it, {}, 1 + skipSlices)`.